# Finding the Angle of Launch for a Cannon Projectile to Hit a Specific Point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

[image: diagram]
A cannon with barrel length of $l$ was placed with its base at the origin $(0,0)$. A ball was fired with the initial speed of $v$ as it leaves the barrel at an angle of $\theta$ above the horizon. After some amount of time, it hits a target at the point $(r,h)$. Assume that there is no friction and that the gravitational acceleration is $g$. What would be the formula for finding $\theta$ if everything else is given?
I have tried writing the $x$ and $y$ position as a function of time, $t$, then equating each position to $r$ and $h$, respectively. I solved both equations for $t$, then setting the results equal, but I ended up with a really complicated equation that's nearly impossible to solve for $\theta$. I have included my attempt below, and would like to know if there is an easier way to tackle this problem.
$l_x=l\cos\theta,\ l_y=l\sin\theta,\ v_x=v\cos\theta,\ v_y=v\sin\theta$
$x(t)=v_xt+l_x=tv\cos\theta+l\cos\theta=r\implies t=\frac{r-l\cos\theta}{v\cos\theta}$
$y(t)=-\frac{1}{2}gt^2+v_yt+l_y=-\frac{1}{2}gt^2+tv\sin\theta+l\sin\theta=h$
$-\frac{1}{2}gt^2+tv\sin\theta+l\sin\theta-h=0\implies t=\frac{-v\sin\theta\pm\sqrt{v^2sin^2\theta+2g(l\sin\theta-h)}}{-g}$
$\frac{-v\sin\theta\pm\sqrt{v^2\sin^2\theta+2g(l\sin\theta-h)}}{-g}=\frac{r-l\cos\theta}{v\cos\theta}$
$gr+gl\cos\theta=v^2\sin\theta\cos\theta\pm v\cos\theta\sqrt{v^2\sin^2\theta+2gl\sin\theta-2gh}$
Here, I run into a problem as I have no idea where to go from here, since the equation looks almost impossible to solve for $\theta$. If there are any insights on how to accomplish this, or a better approach to this problem, I would be interested to know. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Kylorcache. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Hello, Qmechanic. I did read both of those items. I realize how this question can be considered homework-like due to its educational nature. I have added the appropriate tags. I apologize for the misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by changing the coordinate system: put the cannon muzzle at x=0, y=0. Now you have a new distance vertically, $h' = h - l\sin\theta$ and horizontally $r' = r - l\cos\theta$.

The time to travel horizontally:

$$t = \frac{r'}{v\cos\theta}$$

and vertically:

$$h' = v\sin\theta t - \frac12 g t^2$$

When we hit the target, the two values of $t$ are the same, so if we eliminate $t$ we should be able to solve for $\theta$:

$$h' = r'\tan\theta - \frac12 g \left(\frac{r'}{v\cos\theta}\right)^2$$

This is considerably easier than the approach you were taking. Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: Wouldn't there also be a $t$ in the $v\sin\theta$ term? In which case $h'=v\sin\theta\frac{r'}{v\cos\theta}-\frac{g}{2}(\frac{r'}{v\cos\theta})^2$

Comment: Of course - you're right, it is getting late here...

Comment: Haha, I don't blame you. So what I would end up with is a term with $\tan\theta$ and a second term with $\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}$. Nothing really comes to mind on how to solve that for $\theta$, unless $\sec^2\theta=1+\tan^2\theta$ comes into play.

Comment: I think it does... and then you have a quadratic equation in $\tan\theta$. Which you solve like any quadratic equation.

Comment: That does make sense. There is one problem though. I can use the quadratic formula to write $\theta$ as a function of $h'$ and $r'$, but since $h'$ and $r'$ are both dependent on $\theta$, wouldn't I still have $\theta$ on both sides after I substitute $h'$ and $r'$ back in?

Comment: I see your point. You might have to do this iteratively then - since the error terms will get smaller for each subsequent approximation of $\theta$. But yes, maybe this doesn't have a closed form solution... Let us know if you get the answer. I'm off to sleep.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate the effort nonetheless, thanks!